# Change Master Page for Web Application in Sharepoint 2013

Tags: master-page

I've a web application : mycompany.net
 and 3 site collections : mycompany.net/team || mycompany.net/my || mycompany.net/learn
. Now I want to make them look like a web site with menu to navigate to 3 sites. Can you guys give me any way to do this? . In my opinion, I will build my own template and then make it become Master Page of my web application. Is it possible, if yes, how can I do this?

Comment: If it's just 3 site collections, why not just add them as links in the global navigation on each site collection?

Comment: I can handle it, but main thing is I don't know how to customize master page in my web application